# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.view.ActionMode$Callback

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add custom copy paste menu in android 2.3 and getting following error. My code works perfect on android 4.0.

Here is the error

```
04-29 14:52:16.379: I/Process(435): Sending signal. PID: 435 SIG: 9
04-29 14:55:56.709: I/dalvikvm(474): Failed resolving Lcom/example/urdudictionaries/MainActivity$StyleCallback; interface 867 'Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;'
04-29 14:55:56.709: W/dalvikvm(474): Link of class 'Lcom/example/urdudictionaries/MainActivity$StyleCallback;' failed
04-29 14:55:56.719: E/dalvikvm(474): Could not find class 'com.example.urdudictionaries.MainActivity$StyleCallback', referenced from method com.example.urdudictionaries.MainActivity.onCreate
04-29 14:55:56.719: W/dalvikvm(474): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1006 (Lcom/example/urdudictionaries/MainActivity$StyleCallback;) in Lcom/example/urdudictionaries/MainActivity;
04-29 14:55:56.719: D/dalvikvm(474): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0045
04-29 14:55:56.719: D/dalvikvm(474): VFY: dead code 0x0047-00d2 in Lcom/example/urdudictionaries/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
04-29 14:55:56.889: D/dalvikvm(474): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 79K, 51% free 2647K/5379K, external 512K/517K, paused 53ms
04-29 14:55:56.909: D/szipinf(474): Initializing inflate state
04-29 14:55:56.929: D/AndroidRuntime(474): Shutting down VM
04-29 14:55:56.929: W/dalvikvm(474): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.urdudictionaries.MainActivity$StyleCallback
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at com.example.urdudictionaries.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:150)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-29 14:55:56.939: E/AndroidRuntime(474):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);         
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);               
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.maintitlebar);       


        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new StyleCallback());

}


class StyleCallback implements android.view.ActionMode.Callback {


        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode mode,
                MenuItem item) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode,
                Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode,
                Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: [ActionMode.Callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.Callback.html) wasn't added until API level 11.

Comment: So simple solution is not to use it?

Comment: [AppCompat](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding) provides backwards compatibility for the `ActionMode` and `ActionBar` APIs, but the support library doesn't have a way to call `TextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback`, so you'd have to use a custom implementation for that.